# Sentiment analysis on a tibble

Tags: r

Based on http://tidytextmining.com/sentiment.html#the-sentiments-dataset I'm attempting to perform sentiment analysis on a tibble.

Setup the tibble :

```
url <- c( "t1" , "t2")
word <- c( "abnormal" , "good")
n <- c( 1 , 1)
score <- c(1 , 2)
res <- as_tibble(data.frame("url"=url , "word"=word, "n"=n , "score"=score , stringsAsFactors = F))
res
```

creates :

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
    url     word     n score
  <chr>    <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1    t1 abnormal     1     1
2    t2     good     1     2
```

Generate the sentiments :

```
joined_sentiments <- res %>% inner_join(get_sentiments("bing"))
joined_sentiments
```

creates :

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
    url     word     n score sentiment
  <chr>    <chr> <dbl> <dbl>     <chr>
1    t1 abnormal     1     1  negative
2    t2     good     1     2  positive
```

How can I then convert these to a series of graphs where each graph is a specific url, similar to

[image]

src http://tidytextmining.com/sentiment.html#the-sentiments-dataset

As don't have line numbers I'm trying :

```
joined_sentiments %>%
  count(url, index=n, sentiment) %>%
  spread(sentiment, n, fill = 0) %>%
  mutate(sentiment = positive - negative)
```

which returns error :

```
joined_sentiments %>%
+   count(url, index=n, sentiment) %>%
+   spread(sentiment, n, fill = 0) %>%
+   mutate(sentiment = positive - negative)
Error: `var` must evaluate to a single number or a column name, not a double vector
In addition: Warning message:
In if (!is.finite(x)) return(FALSE) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason for the error/warning is the 'n' column already present in the dataset, resulting in change of the column name to 'nn' when `count` is applied as `count` by default creates a 'n' column.

res %>% 
      inner_join(get_sentiments("bing")) %>% 
      count(url, index=n, sentiment)
    #Joining, by = "word"
    # A tibble: 2 x 4
    #    url index sentiment    nn
    #          
    #1    t1     1  negative     1
    #2    t2     1  positive     1

In the subsequent step, we are `spread`ing to 'wide' format with column name specified as 'n' which is not matching to 'nn'.  So either change it to 'nn'

```
res1 <- res %>% 
          inner_join(get_sentiments("bing")) %>% 
          count(url, index=n, sentiment) %>% 
          spread(sentiment, nn, fill = 0) %>%
          mutate(sentiment = positive - negative)
res1
#Joining, by = "word"
# A tibble: 2 x 5
#     url index negative positive sentiment
#   <chr> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#1    t1     1        1        0        -1
#2    t2     1        0        1         1
```

and then with `ggplot`, we can do (with the two rows of data, the output may not look good)

```
ggplot(res1, aes(index, sentiment, fill = url)) +
     geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
     facet_wrap(~url, ncol = 2, scales = "free_x")
```

---

Or remove the column 'n' while creating the 'res' and then the OP's original code would work well

```
res <- tibble(url , word, score)
```